# how do you get the total size of wget recursive without downloading all the files first?

Tags: wget, webserver, recursive, download

- i have something large to download recursively
- the size is estimated to be > 150GB (someone told me this is roughly the size)
- right now i do not have the storage space
- so i need to figure out how large the total size is and then i will do something to get more storage space
- before i can get more storage space i need to figure out the total size
- the target URL is a directory of files hosted by a some sort of http file server

### how do you get the total size of `wget --recursive` without downloading all the files first?

NOTE: this question is only for web pages that contain static content (i.e. not dynamically generated on the fly. i.e. content that has a well defined content length.)

Answer (score 1):

### here's what i found to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
(
cd ${tmpdir}
wget --recursive  -erobots=off --no-parent --spider --server-response http://mirrors.rit.edu/rocky/9.1/BaseOS/x86_64/os/ 2>&1 |grep --line-buffered -i content-length | gawk '{sum+=$2}END{print sum/1e6}'
)
find ${tmpdir} -type d -delete
```

explanation of wget arguments:

- `--recursive` tells `wget` to recurse all the files in the directory
- `-erobots` tells `wget` to continue recursing even though there is a `robots.txt` file
- `--no-parent` tells `wget` to not recurse upwards (i.e. parent) because this is not what i want (and probably not what anyone wants)
- `--spider --server-response` tells `wget` to only print the header of each file

  - **this `--spider` option i think unexpectedly deletes all files on disk and so my download of many Gigabytes and thousands of files was being accidentally deleted by this feature. so i run the command in a temporary directory to stop this behavior from accidently deleting files.**
- `grep` tells is used to grab only the line with the content length in bytes
- `gawk` tells is used to sum the bytes and then print the byte count in MB

Comment: The problem with this is that sometimes the web server does not know the size of the files in advance. Dynamic content would be one reason for this. It’s good that your method worked this time but don’t count on it.

Comment: your raise a very good point. thank you! --> this question/answer does not apply for dynamic content. so i will update one or both to make the problem more well defined.